# Using FileStreamResult to display PDF in browser

Tags: filestreamresult

I am trying to display a PDF file in a browser using the action below.
When this is executed the result is an entire screen that looks like the image attached.  [Rendered result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeOMn.jpg)
It looks like MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf is being ignored. 
The same result with Chrome or Firfox.
What I am missing?

```
[HttpGet]
    public FileResult ViewFile()
    {
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + Server.UrlEncode("file.pdf") + ";");
        var path = @"C:\temp\file.pdf";
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        return new FileStreamResult(stream, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below below code snippet to display a PDF document in browser.

```
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        fileStream.Position = 0;
        return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
```

Comment: I added fileStream.Position = 0;  but it still produces the same result as shown in the attached image. It looks like the browser thinks the file is text not a PDF.

Comment: try by opening the file directly in browser, check it is displayed properly or not.

Comment: The file is a valid pdf the browser is not rendering as PDF. I get �/��$Z����U�m@��

Comment: If use a partial view that contains a embed the pdf is correctly displayed. I also tried returning File(pdfByte, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);  and the garbage chars are displayed.  What am I missing?

Comment: I can't use embed as the pdf is when a stream.